# Tomcat v8+Servlet v3.1 giving 404 error on running a servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

This is the sample servlet that I wrote, nothing fancy:

```
@WebServlet("/SimpleServletPath")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

I am using external installation of Tomcat v8.0 on the computer, which gives correct page on querying `http://localhost:8080/`.

The `Dynamic Web Module` being used in `Eclipse Luna` is `3.1`. Also since I am using the `@WebServlet` annotation, I have not generated or making use of a `web.xml` file.

No matter what I do, Tomcat is always giving me error on running the Servlet.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SimpleServlet/SimpleServletPath
type Status report

message /SimpleServlet/SimpleServletPath

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: in your path "/SimpleServlet/SimpleServletPath" u r not specifying "/SimpleServlet/" anywhere...

Comment: why dont you just right click on your servlet(inside eclipse) and choose `run on server` this will run your servlet giving you the actual path

Comment: @singhakash I am running the servlet by doing right-click -> run on server only

Comment: @Nareshkumar I hope that I've made this clear. Name of the project is `SimpleServlet`. Name of the servlet itself is `SimpleServlet` with `urlPattern="/SimpleServletPath"`

Comment: what is the output of `http://localhost:8080/SimpleServlet/SimpleServlet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it sounds silly, but I had unchecked `Build Automatically` in Eclipse. And I guess that was preventing any changes to my project from being built and deployed to the Tomcat.

Just checked `Build Automatically` and now everything works flawlessly.

`Servlet 3.1` (with/without web.xml) as well as `Servlet 2.5` (with web.xml).